# Show notification message in certain time in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, notifications, laravel-5

I try to show notification message in certain time like the following example

```
    //get all MaintenanceService that assigned to user 
    $ms= MaintenanceService::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
                          ->where('created_at','<', Carbon::now())->get();

    //looping over coun($ms)
    for($x = 0 ; $x< count($ms);$x++) {

         // this var carrying created_at date for $ms[$x] and add 
        // notification_period value for example 60 second
    $firstNot[$x] = $ms[$x]->created_at->addMinutes($ms[$x]->notification_period);

     if(Carbon::now() >  $firstNot[$x]) {
       echo('notification fired at ' .$firstNot[$x]. '<br/>');
     }
   }
```

The above code working well for showing notification message **for once**

but now i need to get `$firstNot` and add to it `$ms[$x]->notification_period`
using `addMinutes()` then show the message now i have `$secondNot`  then `$secondNot->addMinutes(60)` // one more time .

i need to do this process for example ten times

but In fact i don't know how i start, **Any Help**

Comment: Can you please explain your problem in a clearer way?

Comment: simply i want to show notification **msg1** for example `now()` and after 60 second show **msg2** again  and after 60 second from **msg2** show another msg and so on

Comment: Did you read task scheduling or console commands? http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/scheduling maybe these solutions may help you. Simply you can define a cron or console command to do that process for you.

Comment: i have been read it , but i think it's working with CLI not GUI (iam not sure), if you know any way to achieve that with cron job , please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can add `$counter` to get the number of notification msg

**this for make it more readable no more**

```
     $counter = 0;
      while(Carbon::now() > $firstNot[$x]) {
        echo("<div>".'notification ' . ++$counter . ' at ' . $firstNot[$x]  . 
       ' next notification will fire at ' .$firstNot[$x]->addMinutes($ms[$x]->notification_period) 
     .' i will fire every ' . $ms[$x]->notification_period . 'M' .'<br/><br/>'."</div>");
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for participating

Answer (score 1):

I think i found the solution so i will show it for help or improve it
I found the issue in `if()` condition should replace it using `while()`
for looping over the `$firstNot` and in each loop increase `$firstNot->addMinutes($minValue)`

to become the code as the following

```
  $ms= MaintenanceService::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
                         ->where('created_at','<', Carbon::now())->get();

  for($x = 0 ; $x< count($ms);$x++) {

  $firstNot[$x] = $ms[$x]->created_at->addMinutes($ms[$x]->notification_period);

    while(Carbon::now() > $firstNot[$x]) {
      echo('first notification '. $firstNot[$x] . 
     // here get $firstNot and add fo it $ms[$x]->notification_period
      ' next notification will fire at'.$firstNot[$x]->addMinutes($ms[$x]->notification_period) . 
      ' i will fire every ' . $ms[$x]->notification_period .'M'. '<br/>');
            }
}
```

Now I can get all Notification msgs that assigned to user and each 60m in our case show it again **Msg1 after 60m Msg2 after 60m form Msg2 show Msg3 ....**